# How to convert string with concatenation to real string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, hex, md5

I have a string which looks like this on a page response (saved as autoResponse):

```
... hexMD5('\262' + '****' + '\155\135\053\325\374\315\264\062\232\354\242\205\217\034\154\005'); ...
```

In order to capture this, I use:

```
var hex = autoResponse.split('hexMD5(')[1].split(')')[0];
```

This now gives me this string:

```
'\262' + '****' + '\155\135\053\325\374\315\264\062\232\354\242\205\217\034\154\005'
```

If I put this directly into the `hexMD5()` method, it thinks that the `'`, `+` symbols and white space are apart of the secret.

I tried to use `replace()` to remove them like so:

```
while(hex.split("'").length !== 1) hex = hex.replace("'", "");
while(hex.split("+").length !== 1) hex = hex.replace("+", "");
while(hex.split(" ").length !== 1) hex = hex.replace(" ", "");
```

However, when I then do `hexMD5(hex)` it gives me an incorrect hex. Is there anyway I can convert the hex to a string where it combines the strings together as if I was hardcoding it like

```
hexMD5('\262' + '****' + '\155\135\053\325\374\315\264\062\232\354\242\205\217\034\154\005');
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single, much simpler RegExp for this:

```
hex = hex.replace(/' ?\+ ?'/g, '');
```

That says "replace all single-quotes, followed by possibly a space, then a plus, then possibly another space, followed by another single quote" and replaces those matches with nothing, thus removing them. (You need the \ before the + because + is a special character in RegExes that needs to be escaped.)

Comment: Thankyou! Also, adding the addition of `.split("hexMD5('")[1].split("')")[0];` removes the final `''` quotes around it giving me a perfect match. Thanks! Ill accept when I can!